# Кастомная кнопка "< Back" со стандартной возможность вернутся назад кликом или свайом

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

День добрый! Ребята, мне нужно сделать кастомную кнопку "< Back" но со стандартной возможность вернутся назад кликом или свайом. Если я делаю через `initWithCustomView` то естественно что стандартные функции пропадают. Есть ли другие возможности?

Спасибо за любую помощь.

```
UIBarButtonItem* menuButtonView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[Utils customButtonMenuWithHCLogo:NSLocalizedString(@"newsFeed", @"")]];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:menuButtonView];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)p_configureNavigationBar
{
        UIButton *leftViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
        [leftViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(a_pressedNavigationButtonLeft:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItemLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftViewButton];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItemLeft;
}

- (void)a_pressedNavigationButtonLeft:(MHNavigationButton *)navigationButton
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Была когда-то такая же задача, насколько помню, тогда мы ее решали подсунув в initWithCustomView нашу кастомную кнопку (UIButton, уж на нее-то можно повесить все что хочешь как в плане графики, так и в плане дествий), а на кнопку повесили метод дергавший `[self.navigationController popViewVontroller: animated]`. Того кода под рукой сейчас нету, но я в принципе описал все что было, кастомизация кнопки у вас все равно своя

Ну вот, пока писал, [[@Bimawa](/users/10304/bimawa)](/users/10304/bimawa) уже ответил и, что характерно, способ у него такой же :)

Comment: На самом деле, этот способ был где-то на WWDC потом еще раз я его видел на стеке.

Comment: я честно говоря даже не помню откуда он взялся у нас, может и с WWDC, помню только  сам способ

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант:
[change the leftbarbuttonitem color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20423101/1517082)

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem*)itemWithNormalImage:(UIImage*)normalImage
                       pressedImage:(UIImage*)pressedImage
                             target:(id)target
                             action:(SEL)action
{
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:normalImage
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:pressedImage
        forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setImage:pressedImage
        forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, normalImage.size.width, normalImage.size.height);
[button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem* item=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
return item;
}
```